# A problem about solving energy bands by the method of second quantization

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, second-quantization

In hopping model, we can get the Hamitonian as $H_0=-t\sum a^\dagger_ia_{i'}$. Then we take the fourier transform and put the operator  which are in momentum space in the Hamitonian above. However, I found that there will be terms like $blabla~a^\dagger_ka_{k'}$, which is not remained at last when you finally got the energy spectrum like $E_ka^\dagger_ka_k$. So my question is how do these non-diagonal terms vanish.

Comment: Is that the tight-binding model? If so you're missing the h.c. Your $H_0$ is not Hermitian.

Comment: Yeah, it's the tight-binding model. It seems that if $i$ and $i'$ can run all of the lattice, there is no need to add the hc term, and it is Hermitian.

Comment: Aha, so the summation takes care of h.c. and it is Hermitian hence. But its not nearest neighbor if $i$ and $i'$ run over the entire lattice? If so in that case I don't think you can diagonalize the model with Fourier transform, though I'm unsure.

Comment: Well, I think $i$ can run all of the lattice, and keep $i$ and $i'$ to be the nearest ones at the same time. That's what the sum means.

Comment: Then you're making a mistake in your calculation. Without seeing the details we can't know what it is.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get your point. But I also think I make  some mistakes.

Comment: Are you imposing periodic boundary conditions?

Comment: Well, I just wonder how can I eliminate those cross terms. Anyway, those terms are just here when you plug the fourier transform in. I don't know whether periodic boundary can eliminate those terms.

Comment: The correct application of Fourier transform and periodic boundary conditions will diagonalize your Hamiltonian. Without seeing how you tried to this exactly I can not say where you made a mistake so I gave you a link to some lecture notes where this is done.

Answer (score 2):

When you Fourier transform the tight-binding Hamiltonian, $$c_{j,s}=\sum_{k,s} a_{k,s} e^{i R_j k},$$ with periodic boundary conditions, you will be left with a diagonalized Hamiltonian in the desired form.
For details see section 2.3 of these lectures notes, starting on p.18: http://manybody.skku.edu/Lecture%20notes/Solid%20State%20Physics.pdf

Comment: Yeah, I think I find where I made the mistake. I forget to use the anti-commutation relations with $a^\dagger_k$ and $a_{k'}$, this will help me cancel those crossing terms. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Simon.Z If you found Bubble's answer helpful, perhaps you might consider upvoting it.